# Splitting a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Please consider the following list:

```
data={1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3};
```

Now I would like to split the list into 0-sequences and Not-0-sequences as following:

```
{{1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 5, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {3}}
```

All numbers are non-negative `Integer`s, if that helps.

Comment: Not quite the same, but [related](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node368.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Split[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}, Xor[#1 != 0, #2 == 0] &]
```

or more compactly

```
Split[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}, Xnor[#1 == 0, #2 == 0] &]
```

works nicely here. Another way is:

```
SplitBy[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}, Unitize]
```

or

```
SplitBy[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}, Sign]
```

or, as Szabolcs suggests:

```
SplitBy[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}, # == 0 &]
```

Comment: It's probably good to note here that `PossibleZeroQ` does some symbolic processing.  It's not "simple inside".  While using it works, for a simple programming task (on a list of strictly integers) I'd feel more comfortable with `Unitize` or just `# == 0 &`.  Why not include `Unitize` in the answer instead?

Comment: Done. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, not at all, but it seems so easy to offend you... ;P

Comment: @J.M. Offend? No, I just have trouble reading/seeing things sometimes.

Comment: Incidentally this is one of the reasons I like `~infix~` -- it is easier on the eyes despite claims to the contrary.  I guess it's a bit like RPN (which I never learned) -- those who understand it love it, those who don't hate it.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: all styles have their place. On my part, *Mathematica* has a lot of two-argument functions, but I'd only consider infixing a handful of them...

Answer (score 10):

Here's a recursive rule based solution for fun:

```
Clear[f]
f[l_List] := l /. {x__?(# != 0 &) | Longest[x : 0 ..], y___} :> {{x}, Sequence @@ f[{y}]}
f[{x_}] := {{x}}

f[{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}]    
(* {{1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 5, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {3}} *)
```

Comment: Impressive! ... Any easy question in Mma is a seed for very good answers like this one

Comment: +1 for elegance, although note that, while recursion hides it, this will suffer from the same performance hit as if it would be explicitly based on `ReplaceRepeated`, for large lists.

Answer (score 10):

I recently read [*The Little Schemer*](http://amzn.com/0262560992) by Friedman and Felleisen, so the following construction suggests itself:

```
split[{}]={};
split[{Longest[x__?(#>0&)] | Longest[x__?(#==0&)], y___}]:=Join[{{x}},split[{y}]];

In[34]:= split[{1,0,0,0,2,5,2,3,0,0,3}]
Out[34]= {{1},{0,0,0},{2,5,2,3},{0,0},{3}}
```

I make no claim that this is at all practical.

Comment: Scheme was the language for the intro-CS course when I was an undergrad.  I liked it, but it drove the people who already knew C nuts.

Comment: @BrettChampion At one point I made a list of things I liked about Mathematica, and it included the fact that everything is an expression.  Lisp popped up when I researched the roots of this feature.  On a related note, that book really did teach me to write recursions!  (Always ask null?, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to win any awards for efficiency but I had fun putting it together.

```
f[{h_, t__}] := f[{h}, {t}]

f[x___, {a_, b___}, {h_, t__}] := 
  If[
     (h == 0) == (a == 0),
     f[x, {a, b, h}, {t}],
     f[x, {a, b}, {h}, {t}]
  ]

f[x___, y : {_}] := {x, y}

f @ {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3}
```

> ```
> {{1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 5, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {3}}
> ```