# Split list when there is an empty row

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I am trying to split a list when there is an empty row.
I have tried the following:

```
a = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {, ,}, {3, 3, 3}};
b = Split[a, # == Null]
```

but my result is:

```
{{{1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}}, {{Null, Null, Null}}, {{3, 3, 3}}}
```

which is not correctly split.

I would like to have `{1,..}` and `{2,...}` gathered together:

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{Null, Null, Null}}, {{3, 3, 3}}}
```

Comment: A pure function needs to end with `&`: `b = Split[a, # == Null &]`

Comment: Related [(6727)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6727/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read carefully documentation of `Split`, you need its friend [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html):

```
SplitBy[a, MemberQ[Null]]
```

> {{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{Null, Null, Null}}, {{3, 3, 3}}}

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
Split[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {, ,}, {3, 3, 3}},
      ! (MatchQ[#1, {Null ..}] || MatchQ[#2, {Null ..}]) &]
```

Comment: Awesome !! That's what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here two ways to do it using `Split`.

```
a = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {, ,}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}};

With[{p1 = {{_Integer ..} ..}}, Split[a, MatchQ[{#1, #2}, p1] &]
With[{p2 = {{Except[Null] ..} ..}}, Split[a, MatchQ[{#1, #2}, p2] &]]]
```

Both give

> `{{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{Null, Null, Null}}, {{3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}`

The form using pattern `p2` is probably better because it is more general. It will handle

```
c = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, { , ,}, {x, y, z}, {4, 4, 4}};
```

correctly, while the form using `p1` stumbles on the sub-list `{x, y, z}`.

```
With[{p1 = {{Except[Null] ..} ..}}, Split[c, MatchQ[{#1, #2}, p1] &]]
```

> `{{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{Null, Null, Null}}, {{x, y, z}, {4, 4, 4}}}`